# How to calculate sample mean, given the sample variance

Tags: variance, mean, sample

[image]if we are given the sample variance value as 129.77, how can we calculate the sample mean.

Moreover, the following is known:

$\sum x_i^2 = 123\,117.538\,151$

Comment: What other information do you have?

Comment: If this is scaled version of your sample variance, then your sample mean is $0$.

Comment: @user2974951, Other than the ∑x2i, I only have the sample variance value of 129

Comment: What is $\sum x2i$?

Comment: Sorry couldn't write the code correctly. Its the sum of all of the squared values

Comment: @gunes, I really don't know if it is a scaled version of sample variance as this information is missing for me

Comment: One re-interpretation of this question: I will tell you how wide a coin is.  If you can tell me where in the world it is located, you may keep it :-).

Comment: If you have the sample variance, please edit the question. It seems as if you call $\sum x_i^2$ as sample variance.

Comment: @gunes Good point! If indeed the OP knows the variance and the sum of squares, the only information needed to recover the mean would be the sample size and the sign of the mean.

Comment: Thanks @whuber! I know the sample size as well but not sure what you meant by 'sign of the mean'? However I have tried to input all known values in the sample variance equation to get the value of x. Please see the solution as an attached image in my question. Is this the correct way of calculating value for SUM OF X and subsequently the MEAN value?

Comment: The mean may be positive or negative, but the information you have cannot determine which.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the explanation. This is clear!

Answer (score 3):

You can't - you can have different samples with different means, yet having the same variance.

Variance is not a function of the mean.

Comment: Note: it can be done if we make assumptions about the population, such as exponential. Our favorite distribution assumption, normal, does not wrk for this, however.

Comment: @Dave That's incorrect, because the *sample* will not enjoy the same mathematical relationships among its moments as its underlying generative *distribution.*

Comment: whuber brings up a subtle but important point that I missed. Take Poisson$(\lambda)$ as an example, where the population mean and population variance are equal and equal to the $\lambda$ parameter. Our sample, even if it is drawn from a distribution that is perfectly Poisson, (probably) is not perfectly Poisson$(\lambda)$, so the relationship that $\mu = \sigma^2 = \lambda$ does not hold in the sample, despite it holding in the population, so we are not able to say exactly what the mean of the sample would have been if we had calculated it while we still had access to the data.